# Why is my GIT command working on the windows terminal but not working on the VScode IDE terminal?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, command-line-interface, clone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emjqw.png)

My Git command works perfectly on the windows terminal but not on VScode's terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKEpb.png)

I got want I wanted through the windows terminal but our of curiosity why is this the case?

I tried enabling the command line interface option in the Git installation

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. A general guideline : paste *text* not *pictures* - especially for terminal output. Can you please edit your question to replace the links to the actual text (input and output) of your terminal commands ?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Update/install latest version of git. Else to to extensions and in the search bar type: @builtin. This will list all the built-in extensions in vs-code categorized under different sections. In the 'Features' section look for Git extension. Check if it is disabled. Enable it and your version control should start working.

Comment: The mentioned problem has nothing to do with extensions